# I don't understand how to use lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, collections

I'm trying to get a lambda expression to count the amount of odd numbers in a small collection of integers. In general I'm just confused about the syntax and the types I can use with them. So far I have:

```
Collection<Integer> col = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
int count = 0;
count = col.forEach((Integer n) -> { if ((n % 2) != 0) count++;});
```

It says it can't convert from void to int, no idea why that's the error that comes up.

Comment: What's the return type of `forEach`? Your error doesn't have anything to do with lambda expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify local variables from within a lambda. You can use a mutable reference, but it would be much simpler to go with streams:

```
long count = col.stream().filter(n -> n % 2 != 0).count();
```

Comment: Thank you, it's been a few weeks since I learned about them and I forgot some of the finer details.

Comment: @2004DodgeNeon There is [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

Answer (score 0):

The variable count has type **int**. The lambda expression with forEach has type **void**, it's just like running the for loop, it doesn't return anything. So, your assignment

```
count = col.forEach(...)
```

is actually trying to assign void to int.

Comment: Oh I see. In hindsight that's pretty obvious but I haven't slept well haha.